# How do I switch plants in PvZ garden warfare

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare

I’ve been losing in PvZ because I cannot figure out how to switch from my peashooter to my plasma pea.  How do I switch between them?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose between different classes by scrolling left or right when picking your character on the character selection screen: